# Meaning of: Cognitive Dissonance

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to make out the meaning of this expression. So far I've seen meanings in several websites but I couldn't give it a closure (I couldn't fully understand the meaning). I'd be glad if someone could help me with this and if so, put it in a cohesive way.

Comment: Basically, two things that you think are true seem to contradict each other.  Just a two musical notes which seem pleasant when played separately can sound bad ("dissonant") when played together.  How you choose (consciously or unconsciously) to resolve such conflicts determines your personal scientific tendencies, and, to a degree, your personality.

Comment: An example:  Someone believes that the world was created about 6,000 years ago, but also accepts that DNA evidence can exonerate a person charged with rape.

Comment: Thank you people, I think I get it now. Also I found that a psychologist not only wrote about cognitive dissonance but also did an experiment about it.  Thanks again for your time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English but about psychology. See wikipedia on [Cognitive Dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance).

Answer (score 6):

The concept of cognitive dissonance, social psychologist Leon Festinger's primary claim to fame, is a powerful description of human behavior which has a wide, possibly universal, application to the human species. Though relatively easy to define and describe, the concept has generated more academic research, technical papers, and scholarly articles than perhaps any other scientific descriptor of how the human psyche functions in real-world situations.

The primary assumption behind the concept of cognitive dissonance is that people have difficulty juggling two conflicting ideas in their minds at the same time without feeling ill at ease, uncomfortable, and in short: dissonant. Consequently, rather than live with the discomfort the ideas generate, people tend to choose one idea over the other and try to live as best they can with their decision.

For example (and with my tongue planted firmly in my cheek), where sanity is concerned, most normal people don't think it 's possible to be both sane and insane at the same time. They tend to choose one over the other and pretty much stick to that choice. To believe both at the same time simply causes too much dissonance (read: discomfort).

One of my favorite illustrations of the phenomenon of cognitive dissonance involves gambling. You name the game: craps, slots, 21, poker, roulette wheel, or whatever. They all involve a particle of risk (to quote Mr. Merriweather, a character in the film "Little Big Man"), and wherever risk rears its ugly head, poignant human emotions are sure to follow.

Take the gambler who enters a casino with a thousand dollars in his pocket. That is all the money he is willing to risk. Of course, he hopes to double, or triple, or quadruple that amount, but if they're not terribly "lucky" that day they're willing to sacrifice the thou'.

Three hours later our gambler is tapped out. The thou' is gone. Now the sensible thing to do is to leave the casino, lick his wounds, and find another entertainment to occupy his time. Some gamblers, however (and not just gamblers), don't do the sensible thing. Their thought process at this point might go something like this:

> Well, I know that I told myself a thousand bucks was my limit, but I really think my luck will improve if I just get a breath of fresh air and then give it another try. I do have a cash reserve in my bank account, and if I take another thousand from that account, I just know my luck will change and I'll get the original thousand back and then quit. Yeah, that's the plan, and this time I'm sticking to it.

Now a normal person would not likely have gone into a casino in the first place with a thousand bucks to blow on gambling. A problem gambler, however, is not your normal person. Rather than admit defeat and move on, which is what most normal folks would do, he refuses to admit defeat because to do so causes too much mental dissonance. Normal people "cut their losses" to banish the dissonance; gamblers "double down" to recoup what they've lost, and in so doing simply compound the dissonance when they lose again.

It's very sad, really. Again, there's sanity and there's insanity. The normal gambler says to himself, "I really blew it, but I'll get over it and I'll try not to make the same mistake twice." The problem gambler, on the other hand, rationalizes his mistake and in an effort to prove the legitimacy of his rationalization engages in the same destructive behavior again and again.

Lest you think cognitive dissonance is always a bad thing, I assure you it is not. If you are ever on the brink of helping yourself to a piece of jewelry in a department store without first paying for it, then cognitive dissonance might just keep you from getting arrested. The same goes for living beyond your means with the help of a plethora of credit cards.

Another point I should make is that some people can live with a great deal of dissonance, whereas some other people cannot. What causes *you* cognitive dissonance might cause barely a ripple in the psyche of someone else. I guess, however, that in the psyche of a psychopath, nothing causes dissonance--nothing immoral or illegal, that is. If anything, the sociopathic murderer might feel dissonance by not having killed more people than he did before he got caught!

By the way, have you ever gotten the urge to get really serious about exercising and getting physically fit? Perhaps you've gone out and spent $850 on the best running shoes and all the best accouterments money can buy that prove you are really serious about getting fit. Your plan is to jog five mornings a week. You'll start with short distances and gradually increase the distances until . . ..

**NEWS FLASH**

I just felt cognitive dissonance for having spent this amount of time writing an answer to your question. I'm tempted to scrap the whole answer and move on to something else, but . . . I've already spent an hour writing what I've written, so I may as well see it to its conclusion. But then again . . . maybe not. I really do need to focus on something else, and I promised my wife I'd clean the garage . . .. What to do? What to do?

Get the point?

Comment: I think you were doing pretty well until you got into your gambling analogy.  Pathological gambling is a problem with impulse control and addiction more than it is a problem with basic perceptions.  And in making this analogy you downplay many situations where cognitive dissonance is a really serious problem, such as in family relationships.

Comment: @HotLicks: Agreed, problem gamblers are perhaps struggling more with the symptoms of impulse control and addiction than cognitive dissonance (CD). Perhaps I should edit my answer to clarify that even degenerate gamblers (or degenerate ______s--you fill in the blank) began their downward spiral by experiencing CD, at least initially. Do you have a representative anecdote or illustration as to how cognitive dissonance might play out in family troubles? Almost certainly, the idea of divorce in a spouse's mind, at least initially, triggers strong CD, especially in the longer-lasting marriages.

Comment: I think the "simple" case of discovering that a spouse is cheating on you is pretty classic, as are situations where a child is caught in-between battling mother and father.  The child thinks the world of both mother and father, but they are both telling him that the other parent is evil.

Comment: It occurs to me that sports fans must deal with CD frequently, and have many different strategies for doing so.  Of course most simply accept that their "heroes" are human and can fail at times, but others must somehow concoct an excuse for when their favorite team loses, blaming it on a single player, poor coaching, bad refereeing, field conditions, etc.  I've never quite understood the rewards of spectator sports, but perhaps this "CD therapy" is one benefit (though, as elsewhere, how one deals with CD implies how they deal with life in general).

Answer (score 2):

There are two meanings to the term Cognitive Dissonance.

The first, or original meaning, is a technical term from the field of psychology. Cognitive dissonance here is the feeling of mental discomfort or anxiety one feels when one has conflicting beliefs. Cognitive Dissonance theory predicts that someone in such a state will try to resolve the dissonance as quickly as possible.

The second, more common meaning of cognitive dissonance is the phenomenon of believing two contradictory things at once. There is no particular suggestion of mental discomfort. So, to say someone has cognitive dissonance is simply to say that they have contradictory beliefs. This meaning is incorrect insofar as it is  a misuse of a technical term, but since it is the most commonly used meaning, it would be a losing battle to try to resist it. Personally, I avoid using this meaning and use the term doublethink instead.

Comment: Believing two contradictory things at once (and suppressing that decision) is one of the strategies for handling cognitive dissonance.  It's not inconsistent with the "original" meaning.  But if someone happens to believe two contradictory things and doesn't know they're contradictory (eg, petroleum comes from ugly polluting wells but gasoline comes from a nice clean pump) then no dissonance exists.

Comment: @HotLicks, If you are saying that simple logical contradiction is not cognitive dissonance and it would be a misuse of the term to call it that, then I would agree with you. Nevertheless, that is how many people use it. For instance, I found the following quote on the COCA corpus. It is George Will on ABC. He suggests that the administration has cognitive dissonance, but I don't think he is suggesting that they are feeling dissonance. Rather, he is merely suggesting that they are being inconsistent. (Quote to follow.)

Comment: George Will: "But a huge turnaround doesn't explain the cognitive dissonance of this administration. It's campaigning across the country in what it calls ' recovery summer, ' postulate being we're in a recovery, but, they say, we really need another stimulus, because the first two stimuli did not bring us a recovery."

Comment: An important point about cognitive dissonance is that the individual is often not consciously aware of it -- they're dealing with it at a subconscious level.  But, it is theorized, dealing with the dissonance subconsciously is often more stressful and disruptive (both individually and socially) than facing it directly.

Comment: (By the way, you appear to have misquoted George Will.  I can't get a clear look at the entire text, but what I see is "a huge turnaround doesn't explain *that*", where the meaning of *that* appears to be the unemployment rate.)